# How to Calculate IoU for Polygon Segmentation images in YOLOv8 using Python

Tags: python, math, image-processing, set, yolov8

Please help me to calculate IoU for Polygon Segmentation of images segmented by yolov8 segment module.

I have a predicted mask that is segmented by yolov8 and a ground truth mask.

The ground truth mask has been obtained after converting json file to mask (using `shape_to_mask()` utility function). The JSON file is the annotated pixel coordinates file.
Annotation has been done using the labelme tool.

Here is what I have tried:

```
pred_mask=(rs[0].masks.masks[0].numpy()*255).astype("uint8")

#some code ommitted here

    
with open(pt_json,"r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    dj=json.load(f)
grount_truth_mask=labelme.utils.shape_to_mask((dj['imageHeight'],dj['imageWidth']),dj['shapes'][0]['points'],shape_type=None,line_width=1,point_size=1)

pred_area=st.resize(pred_area,(640,480),order=0,preserve_range=True,anti_aliasing=False)
mask_area=st.resize(mask_area,(640,480),order=0,preserve_range=True,anti_aliasing=False)


pred_area=pred_area.ravel().copy()
mask_area=mask_area.ravel().copy()

pred_area=pred_area==1
mask_area=mask_area==1


intersection = np.sum(pred_area*mask_area)
union=pred_area.sum()+mask_area.sum()-intersection
iou=np.mean(intersection/union)
```

I am getting IoU=0.0 for all images.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `pred_area=pred_area==1; mask_area=mask_area==1`

Comment: For considering only those pixel values that are 1

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try provided function from YOLO: ultralytics.utils.metrics.mask_iou(mask1, mask2, eps=1e-07).

Details can be seen here: https://docs.ultralytics.com/reference/utils/metrics/#ultralytics.utils.metrics.mask_iou

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to experiment with yolov8, so I cant provide any specific answer. However, in more general terms, to compute IoU when you have the ground truth and prediction masks, you can simply use numpy.

```
import numpy as np 

# Create two random masks
y_true = np.greater_equal(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(512,512)), 0.0)    # Random true mask
y_pred = np.greater_equal(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(512,512)), 0.0)    # Random pred mask

# Compute the Intersection over Union
intersection = np.logical_and(y_true, y_pred)                                       # Compute Intersection
union = np.logical_or(y_true, y_pred)                                               # Compute the Union
IoU = np.divide(intersection.sum(), union.sum())                                    # Compute Intersection divided by Union
print(f"Now the intersection over union is computed to be {IoU:.2f}")               # Print results
>>> Now the intersection over union is computed to be 0.33
```

But again, I wouldn't know if there are any other, better optimized ways to directly use the information from the JSON and thus avoid conversions.